# After I change /etc/apt/sources.list...why doesn't it take effect?

Tags: linux, unix, aptitude

Do I have to restart something?

Edit: 
sudo apt-get update has no effect.

When I search this on another machine with the SAME sources.list, it works. But, it still doesn't work on this machine.

```
sudo aptitude search sun-java6-jdk
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to run "apt-get update"...

Comment: That still doesn't work.

Comment: What did you add to /etc/apt/sources.list?

Answer (score 3):

After editing any configuration files in /etc/apt, you generally need to do an update;

```
apt-get update
```

This allows apt to update itself, it's configuration and the server(s) it queries for packages.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to double check that you've got the multiverse repository included. The sun packages are in that one. For example, if you've got:

deb http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/ubuntu/ jaunty main restricted

you can tack on multiverse to the end to add it.

deb http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/ubuntu/ jaunty main restricted multiverse